# get name and email in exchange for free PDF

Tags: wordpress, email

We would like to get leads by offering a free PDF in exchange for name and email.  Ideally, would like to eliminate bogus/spammy leads before either emailing them the PDF or allowing them into an online library where they could download it themselves. Any suggestions about the best way to go about this?

WordPress 4.8.1

CiviCRM 4.7.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For emailing the PDF my approach would be to use a mix of Forms(WP plugin)/[Profiles](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/organising-your-data/profiles/) and [Scheduled reminders](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/email/scheduled-reminders/) or [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules). For granting access to an online PDF library I suggest you ask a separate question.

**Setup**

1. Create a custom activity type ie *PDF request*, and a couple of message templates, one for the welcome/thank you email on request (ie activity status Scheduled) and second one with the actual PDF or link to the PDF, when approved (ie activity status Completed).
   You can go cray cray and create your own, more descriptive, statuses ie *For review*.
2. Set up a Scheduled reminder or CiviRule for the *PDF request* activity with status Scheduled to send the welcome/thank you email.
3. Set up a Scheduled reminder or CiviRule for the *PDF request* activity with status Completed to send the PDF/link to PDF email.

**Workflow**

User fills in form/profile and submits it, contact and *PDF request* activity with status *Scheduled* is created on form submission, user receives welcome email, admin is notified, admin reviews contact/lead and approves the lead updating activity status to *Completed*, lead receives PDF/link to PDF email. With **CiviRules** you can create even more powerful and crazy workflows!

**Implementation**

- The Profile path would need a bit of custom development, using the appropriate [form/profile hooks](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/) in an [extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/) to create a *PDF request* activity type with status Scheduled on form submission that would trigger the described workflow.
- Using Forms you have a couple of options, the [Gravity Forms CiviCRM](http://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/) integration (paid add-on for Gravity Forms) and the [Caldera Forms CiviCRM](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm#caldera-forms-civicrm) integration (free and open source), both will allow you to create an activity on form submission without the need of custom development.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the developer of the Caldera Forms CiviCRM integration.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Download Manager plugin for WordPress. There are several out there.

Comment: Thanks, Carl!  Wondering if there's any way to integrate this with CiviCRM, such that the leads would become contacts in CiviCRM.

Comment: That would depend on the plugin. Find one that requires WP account creation before download. Then when you sync users with Civi it will create new contacts in civi.